# Beautiful Soup 4, findAll

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My code is this

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url=https://www.chembid.com/results/?q=124-07-2&sort=price
my_url='https://www.chembid.com/results/?q=124-07-2&sort=price'

# opening up connection grapping the page
uClient=uReq(my_url)
page_html=uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#html parser
page_soup=soup(page_html,"html.parser")


for Container in Containers:
        name=Container.div.div.span

        title_container=Container.findAll("a",{"class":"supplier"})
        supplier=title_container[0].text
```

And what im trying to do is now to use bs4 to findAll

```
>>> cas_no=Container.findAll("span",{"class":"regular-small-regular-small-font block"})
```

in this code

Factory supply high quality 99% min Octanoic acid/caprylic acid CAS 124-07-2 used in the manufacture of dyes, drugs, spices
                
                    
                        
                            Verifizierter Anbieter -->
                            
                            
                        
                    
                
            
        
        
        
                              -->
        
            Shandong Baovi Energy Technology Co., Ltd.
        
        CChina
        CAS-No.: 124-07-2
        Quality/Grade: Agriculture Grade,Electron Grade,Food Grade,Industrial Grade,Medicine Grade,Reagent Grade
        www.alibaba.com
    
    
        $0.25 - 3.68
        per Kilogram, FOB
        
        
            Show offer

And what im trying to find is the name, supplier, Cas-no, quality and price.

Thanks

Comment: hi. you really should supply the full code of what you have tried/done. You said you tried `findAll`, but I don't see where or how. Also, how did you obtain the HTML? If you did something like a requests.get(url), then include that and you don't need to paste the whole html text here, we could just obtain it that way.

Comment: >>> cas_no=Container.findAll("span",{"class":"black-bold-font block"})

for Container in Containers:
  name=Container.div.div.span

Comment: Like that or doesnt it make sense?

Comment: better, but go back now and add that into the original post by editing it.include as much of the code as you can. ie. show all your the steps before that is leading up. like i see you have `Container`. Again, where did that come from? it's better (at least for me) to have as much context and supporting info that I can

Comment: I can't add the code from the webpage im crying to scrape... Stackflows wont allow me to post the amount of code

Comment: thats fine. this is what you needed to post. Now there should be enough info for others to look through to help. One last thing, edit your post to include what your desired output is. Yes, you're trying to use findAll, but to ultimately do what? What info are you trying to ultimately pull?

Comment: Like this @chitown88?

Comment: Did the solution below not work?

Comment: Hi @chitown88 - it did do the job. Thanks! I've been working on my own code, so didn't see your reply. 

No i would like to create a csv file. Or perhaps use pandas, to analyze and visualize the data.The goal is build a very comprehensive library so any suggestions are welcome (to handle the amount of data best).

Answer (score 0):

so first thing I'm seeing is your trying to iterate through your `Containers` object, but never stored that as anything. So you'll need to have that stored before iterating through that.

hopefully someone will post a more robust solution, but in terms of what is pulled and what you're asking as an output, this will pull it from that specific page. There are a few parts that are not present so I had to account for those and if they weren't there, just have a null. None the less, this should get you going:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd

results = pd.DataFrame()

my_url='https://www.chembid.com/results/?q=124-07-2&sort=price'

# opening up connection grapping the page
uClient=uReq(my_url)
page_html=uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#html parser
page_soup=soup(page_html,"html.parser")

containers = page_soup.find_all('div', {'class':"result-horizontal-wrapper"})


for container in containers:

    name = container.div.div.span.text
    if container.find('a' , {'class':'supplier'}):
        supplier = container.find('a' , {'class':'supplier'}).text
    else:
        supplier = 'n/a'

    span_cas_qulity = container.find_all('span', {'class':'regular-small-font block'})

    cas_no = [x.text for x in span_cas_qulity if 'CAS' in x.text]
    quality = [x.text for x in span_cas_qulity if 'Quality/Grade' in x.text]

    if cas_no != []:
        cas_no = cas_no[0]
    else:
        cas_no = None

    if quality != []:
        quality = quality[0]
    else:
        quality = None

    span_price = container.select('span.black-bold-font-big')[0].text
    span_rate = container.select('span.block.regular-small-font.price')[0].text

    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[name, supplier, cas_no, quality, span_price, span_rate]], columns = ['name','supplier','cas_no','quality','price','rate'])

    results = results.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop = True)
```